# O nome do arquivo Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-aws

Estou salvando um arquivo no AWS s3 da amazon, o arquivo está sendo salvo mas ele coloca um underline e um número na frente, conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E isso está me atraplando na hora de pegar a url do pdf pra mostrar o pdf pro usuário, teria como tirar esse número, ou uma função que pega a URL do objeto?

Tentei essa mas não traz a URL do Objeto:

```
$Url=Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);
```

Código que está salvando o arquivo no servidor:

```
 $filenamewithextension = $request->file('doc')->getClientOriginalName();

        $dia=date('d/m/Y');
        $horario=date("H.i.s");
        $id=Auth::user()->id;
        $filename ='teste';


        $extension = $request->file('doc')->getClientOriginalExtension();


        $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;


        Storage::disk('s3')->put($filenametostore, fopen($request->file('doc'), 'r+'), 'public');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

na linha

```
$filenametostore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
```

é onde é inserido o numero, remova o `'_'.time().'.'` e este número não ira aparecer (deverá ficar assim: `$filename.$extension`) mas tome cuidado, alguém criou este código desta maneira porque podem haver conflitos de nomes.